# Explain me context of these functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

If the weight of a pet rabbit in pounds is a function of its age in years. Call this function g and let a be the the current age of the rabbit. Also, let h be the inverse of g.

$g(a)+1$

$g(2a)$

$h(5)$

Can someone explain me the meaning of each function in the context of the given info. This is not a real question. I need to understand the meaning of each of these in order to do the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $g(a)$ is the weight of the rabbit at age $a$, and since $a$ is the current age of the rabbit, $g(a)$ is the current weight of the rabbit. Thus, $g(a)+1$ is one pound more than the current weight of the rabbit.

$2a$ is twice the rabbit’s current age, so $g(2a)$ is the what the rabbit will weigh when it is twice as old as it is now.

The function $g$ takes the rabbit’s age as input and gives its weight at that age as output; $h$ is the inverse function, so it does exactly the opposite. That is, it takes a weight as input and gives as output the age at which the rabbit weighed that much. Thus, $h(5)$ is the rabbit’s age when it weighed (or will weigh) $5$ pounds.

$$\begin{align*}
g(\text{age})&=\text{weight at that age}\\
h(\text{weight})&=\text{age at which that weight was attained}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Hey Brian, after reading how you defined the functions $g$ and $h$, I was wondering if we can in general (while it may be long winded) define a function simply by using *words* as long as our description adheres to what it means for a relation to be a function? For example: "$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^{2}$", could we say instead "$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)$ is the square of $x$"?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: It’s certainly possible, just as it’s possible to express the quadratic formula entirely in words, but it’s rarely a good idea, as it almost always obfuscates matters.